# How can I program a StreamReader in my app android?

Tags: java, android, networking, client

I am to develop an Android application that receives a message from server but I can connect to server but can't receive a message because when I clicked on Button connect blocks. I think it's because of the cycle but do not know how to resolve this situation in another way and would appreciate your help.

In short I want to know if there's another way to detect when I receive a message and presents it.

**Update: I found the solution like this:**

```
String IP;

String comando;

PrintWriter msgout;

BufferedReader msgin;

Socket socket;

    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;



public void connect(){ //Function to Button connect

    IP = edit.getText().toString();

    try {

     InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(IP); //TCPServer.SERVERIP

     Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 4444); //Porta 4444 serverAddr
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new  OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
     msgout = out;

     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
     msgin = in;

 zav.text1.setText("Connectado.");

  //Wait to mensages
  mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread();
  mConnectedThread.start();

     } catch (Exception e) {
         text1.setText("Erro! Não conectado." + e);
    }
}

public void send(String message){

     try {

         msg.println(message);


     } catch(Exception e) {
         text1.setText("Erro! Comando não enviado." + e);
 } 
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

    public void run(){

     while(true){

         //Read
     try {

                String str = msgin.readLine();
                 text1.setText(str);

              } catch(Exception e) {

                  text1.setText("Error" + e);

              } 
         }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried Push Notification? Here is a good place to start http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/

Comment: I find the solution better see in up :)